# Windows Service ignores UID and PWD in connection string stored in registry

Tags: c#, sql-server, registry, connection-string

I have developed a Windows Service which stores and retrieves its MSSQL connection string in the registry. However I am experiencing that when my service attempts to connect with the string retrieved from the registry it blatantly ignores the UID and PWD specified.

I then compiled and ran the application as a console application and naturally that worked, since the console application was run with the rights of my own user account, whereas the service was run with the Local System account. The service connected successfully to the database when I specified that the service should be run as my own user account.

My conclusion is that when retrieved from the registry an application for some reason does one or both of the following:

- Ignores the UID and PWD specified.
- Automatically assume that the connection should be made in Trusted mode (Trusted_Connection=true)

It is worth mentioning that I have indeed specified Trusted_Connection=false in the connection string stored in the registry.

This is my connection string:

```
SERVER=.\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=mydb;UID=myid;PWD=mypwd
```

Is anyone able to shed some light on this matter? I would very much like to be able to utilize the user id and password stored in my connection string.

Comment: Can you post the complete connection string (just obscuring uid,pwd, and server, instance and DB names, if necessary, but keeping the rest intact)? ADO.Net (and similar systems) just treat the connection string as a string, they have no way to determine that the string was obtained by reading the registry.

Comment: I've added it to the original post now.

Comment: does local service have rights to the registry location you are storing the info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you have SQL Server Authentication switched on?

With integrated authentication (recommended) you need to use change the service Run-As account to an account which has a SQL Server login.

I.e.

- Turn ON Trusted_connection. Just ... don't turn it off.
- Create a user DOMAIN\USR_MYSERVICE.
- Grant the appropriate machine and database permissions to the account.
- Set the service to run as that account.

Comment: Thanks, but I decided to go with using a connection string in app.config instead of going via the registry. That solved it for some strange reason. I'll accept your answer though since it provides the solution for the original problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Check that SQL is configured for Standard Security as specifying the username and password will utilise Standard Security not integrated.  So you cannot use a windows account to access the database in this manner.

The alternative and usually preferred method is to run your service as a windows account and access using integrated security.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266913(v=vs.60).aspx